# Check whether specific values exist in a data frame column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in which the 92nd value of variable `exposure_spline` is 25, but when I run the `%in%` operator to check if 25 exists in the specified column, the output is `FALSE`, as shown below.

Are there any other ways to check whether a specific value exists in a data frame column?

```
base$exposure_spline[92]

[1] 25

> 25 %in% base$exposure_spline

[1] FALSE
```

Comment: hard to reproduce this without sample data.

Comment: +1 for @Wimpel's comment; as it is; your code should give `TRUE`, but without sample data is hard to figure it out.

Comment: Problem could be a floating point error... are you sure `base$exposure_spline[92]` is an integer?

Comment: @Wimpel Thanks, I couldn't reproduce the output with sample data. My data frame consists of 702 entries in which "exposure_spline" goes from 2.4 to 50 with replacement. For "exposure_spline" greater than 25, the output is like the one presented above.

Comment: Could you show: `print(base$exposure_spline[92], digits=22)` ?

Comment: @Sirius Thanks! The output is 24.999999999999999. It seems that this solves my question. Thank you all.